# How to build URL for string and add to list in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a list like below ticketList and need a ResultList as below with a hyperlink attached

ticketList = [JR8908,JR7676,JR7687,JR8798]

I want the result
ResultList : [ [JR8908](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8908),[JR7676](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7676),[JR7687](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7687),[JR8798](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8798)]

Hyperlink would be - http://localhost:8080/browse/ticketID

End point will change for each ticket, it will be ticket ID

Tried Code :

```
ticketList = ["JR8908","JR7676","JR7687","JR8798"]
finalList = [] 

ticketList.eachWithIndex { ticket, index ->
            println ticket
    replacedstring = ticket.replaceAll("$ticket", "<a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/$ticket'>$ticket</a>")
        finalList.add(replacedstring)
}
        println finalList
```

finalist result is below :

```
[<a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8908'>JR8908</a>, <a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7676'>JR7676</a>, <a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7687'>JR7687</a>, <a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8798'>JR8798</a>]
```

But,I want it like : [ [JR8908](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8908),[JR7676](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7676),[JR7687](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7687),[JR8798](http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8798)]

Comment: Please update your question with the code you tried and how it fails.

Comment: @ou_ryperd Updated the code, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Use collect with String interpolation:

```
def ticketList = ["JR8908","JR7676","JR7687","JR8798"]

def finalList = ticketList.collect{ "<a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/$it'>$it</a>" }

assert finalList.toString() == '[<a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8908'>JR8908</a>, <a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7676'>JR7676</a>, <a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR7687'>JR7687</a>, <a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/JR8798'>JR8798</a>]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable formatting:

```
replacedstring = ticket.replaceAll($ticket, "<a href='http://localhost:8080/browse/$ticket'>${ticket}</a>")
```

It looks like you want the output to be strings but your code is printing a list. You will have to iterate over the list:

```
finalList.each { println it }
```

If you want hyperlinks, you will have to put it in HTML.

Comment: It's the same nothing changes

Comment: I changed my answer. Please look again

Comment: After removing Array from quotes it worked!  from "$ticket"  to ticket